# How to get ATAPI SMART Data according to disks using C#/.NET

Tags: c#, windows, hard-drive

I want to write an application that monitors the status of a disk or more disks in a system.

I found that i can manage one disk via WMI "root/wmi" and the MSStorageDriver and query these for the actual values (data and threshold), followed below link
 - http://wutils.com/wmi/root/wmi/msstoragedriver_atapismartdata/ 
So far, it worked well  :-)

However, I have not managed multiple disks until now. I don't know how to get SMART Data according to disks

Could anyone help me resolve this issue?

Many thanks,
Quyen

Answer (score 0):

I tried and succeed, I would like to share the answers for this issue

- Get PNPDeviceID
- Get InstanceName of PNPDevice accordingly
- Get S.M.A.R.T data from InstanceName

Example code

```
public string   PNPDeviceID
    {
        set
        {
            this.m_PNPDeviceID = value;
            this.InstanceName = null;
            this.QueryObjATAPISmartData = null;

            SearcherPnPDeviceId = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSWmi_PnPDeviceId");
            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in SearcherPnPDeviceId.Get())
            {
                if (queryObj["PNPDeviceID"] != null)
                {
                    if (this.PNPDeviceID.ToUpper() == queryObj.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID").ToString().ToUpper())
                    {
                        if (queryObj["InstanceName"] != null)
                        {
                            this.InstanceName = queryObj["InstanceName"].ToString();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (this.InstanceName != null)
            {

                SearcherATAPISmartData = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSStorageDriver_ATAPISmartData");
                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in SearcherATAPISmartData.Get())
                {
                    if (queryObj["InstanceName"] != null)
                    {
                        if (this.InstanceName.ToUpper() != queryObj.GetPropertyValue("InstanceName").ToString().ToUpper())
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    this.QueryObjATAPISmartData  = queryObj;
                    break;
                }  
      }
```

}

After that, you could get any properties of QueryObjATAPISmartData

Regards,
Quyen